# Elementary question about new environment

Tags: environments

I want to create new environment without a "closing argument".
For example,

```
\MakeLowercase{\textsc{MAKE LOWERcase textsc}}
```

to have all text in small caps independently from upper- or lowercase inside the text. How can I create such an environment?

Comment: you dont want an enviornment you want a command `\newcommand\foo[1]{\textsc{\MakeLowercase{#1}}}` then `\foo{this}`

Comment: You're sure you want an *environment*? As in `\begin{makelc}...\end{makelc}`?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, if I have a long text with a lot of paragraphs, it seems to me more confortable to write `\begin{foo} paragraph 1 | new paragraph 2 ... | new paragraph m /end{foo}` instead of write all times the command for every paragraph

Answer (score 2):

Try the [environ package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/environ).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{test}
{\textsc{\MakeLowercase{\BODY}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{test}
THIS IS A TEST
\end{test}
\end{document}
```

Everything between `\begin{test}` and `\end{test}` is scooped up and stored in the macro `\BODY`.

Comment: What advantage using `environ` package? In any case, my problem is to put together two different arguments as `MakeLowercase` and `textsc`...

Comment: @user41063 --- How would you do this without `environ`? Adding `\textsc` to the example is trivial; I have edited the answer.

Comment: Hitertho I didn't know `environ` package, but a lot of environment can be built without it... In any case, thanx!